# Bootstrap alert auto closing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a simple JQuery script to auto close each alerts on my web page in different time periods.

This is my JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
        var alert = $('div.alert[auto-close]');
        alert.each(function() {
            var time_period = $(this).attr('auto-close'); 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).alert('close');
            }, time_period);
        });
     });
```

Here are my two sample alerts:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" auto-close="3000">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                alert one
            </div>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert" auto-close="5000">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                alert two
            </div>
```

Each alert has a custom attribute with value, which is used as alert closing time period.

For some reason alert closing is not working.

Comment: try: `var this_alert = $(this);` below time_period var. Then in setTimeout instead of `$(this).alert('close');` do: `this_alert.alert('close')`

Comment: `$(this)` is different inside the `setTimeOut` callback scope. cache it. check my answer below.

Comment: Ya, now I understood what causes the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this)` was changed inside the `setTimeout` scope. Cache it in a variable. `that` in my example.

```
$(function() {
  var alert = $('div.alert[auto-close]');
  alert.each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var time_period = that.attr('auto-close');
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.alert('close');
    }, time_period);
  });
});
```

**WORKING SNIPPET:**

```js
$(function() {
  var alert = $('div.alert[auto-close]');
  alert.each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var time_period = that.attr('auto-close');
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.alert('close');
    }, time_period);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="moo" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" auto-close="3000">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  alert one
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert" auto-close="5000">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  alert two
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Iceman its working. you are a life saver :) I will accept the answer after 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.on("DOMSubtreeModified")` on parent element:

```html
<div id="messages"></div>
<script>
    // If anything gets appended in #messages, timer is set to remove first element
    $("#messages").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
        var firstChild = this.firstChild;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(firstChild).alert("close"); //You are looking for this
        }, 2000);
    })
</script>
```